# How can Ubuntu Core be installed to lxd?

Tags: system-installation, ubuntu-core, lxd

As described by http://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-core-in-lxd-containers, [Ubuntu Core](http://ubuntu.com/core) can be installed via http://snapcraft.io/lxd by executing `lxc launch images:ubuntu-core/16 ubuntu-core`. The tutorial is outdated because the most new version of [Ubuntu Core](http://ubuntu.com/core) is appearing to be 20 instead of 16, so I did execute `lxc launch images:ubuntu-core/20 ubuntu-core`, which has failed to do what it should have done. What should be done?

```
$ lxc launch images:ubuntu-core/20 ubuntu-core

Creating ubuntu-core
 
Error: Failed instance creation: Failed getting image: Failed parsing
stream: 
Get "https://uk.images.linuxcontainers.org/streams/v1/index.json": x509: 
certificate has expired or is not yet valid: 
current time 2021-09-01T15:42:30+01:00 is after 2021-09-01T12:00:00Z
```

Comment: You should try again. Based on the output you showed, it seems it was just an issue of an expired certificate. The certificate looks updated now https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiwF2.png. If you still receive a different error output, update your question with that output, pleaes.

Comment: @Dan, please visit http://askubuntu.com/questions/1362217.